# Power Automate error with Trigger Condition: The power flow's logic app flow template was invalid

Tags: power-automate

I try to add a Trigger Condition in "When a new email arrives (V3)" - Settings

The Trigger should check the email subject

I get an error :

> The power flow's logic app flow template was invalid.
> The template condition expression 'contains(triggerOutputs()?['body/subject'],'ical')' at line '1' and column '2519' is not valid template language expression

I have tried to replace single quote with doube quote, but doesn't help

What what be the correct condition ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put an @ in front of it. Untested but that’s a requirement and the rest of your expression looks fine.

```
@contains(triggerOutputs()?['body/subject'],'ical')
```